# How can I call a URL in Qwebview in qt?

Tags: qt

I have a qwebview in my program with the name `websitecaller`.
I just want to call http://google.com to that `webview{websitecaller}`.

The code I am using

```
QUrl url="http://www.google.com";
ui->websitecaller->load(url);
```

results in the following error

```
error: conversion from ‘const char [46]’ to non-scalar type ‘QUrl’ requested
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
QUrl url="http://www.google.com";
```

to

```
QUrl url("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: thank u so much chris.i go through the http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qurl.html...i came to know wher i make the mistake....thanks alot